# How to bring Internet to a DD-WRT router from another router?

Tags: networking, home-networking, dd-wrt, setup

I have a new Internet connection that came with a preconfigured modem-router. That works really well but it has only 2 ethernet port and no wireless. So I would like to connect my other router running DD-WRT to connect all my wired and wireless devices.

My issue is that I don't really understand what mode I have to chose for my DD-WRT router. Should I [bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Bridging) or [repeat](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeating_Mode_Comparisons) the network?

I am confused and I would really appreciate some help with that! Also I want to precise that I only want to use the routing functionality of the DD-WRT router because the ISP modem router is extremely basic and does allow any configuration...

Here is a schema of the desired network:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want all your devices/computers on a separate network from the modem/router?  If you setup your DD-WRT as an [Access Point](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) you can keep everything on the same network (`192.168.1.x`) and keep your setup a bit simpler.

Comment: Comment by @heavyd is right - the original page you linked to is if your DD-WRT router was connecting via wireless to your ISP router.

Comment: @ernie Yeah actually I made a mistake and wanted to put links for bridging and repeating modes. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link is about repeating an existing wireless signal to extend its range.  You just want the default settings on the router, and you just plug it in as you have described and it will play.

In your diagram you show two different networks ( 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x ), but nothing other than the router on the first network.  This is effectively what you will have if you connect the modem to the wan port of the router, and change the address of the router from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.2.1.  There is really no need to do that though, and in fact, if you want to plug a computer into the second port on the modem and have it speak with the rest of your devices, you *don't* want to do it that way.  Don't use the WAN port on the router, disable the DHCP service on the router, and all of the computers, no matter which device they are plugged into, will get their IP address from the modem and be able to see each other.

Comment: I don't mind having 2 networks but I only want my devices to connect to the DD-WRT router and use its DHCP functionality. The modem-router from the ISP has really no configurability. I updated my question.

Comment: @Ucodia, then just plug and play, no configuration needed.

Comment: Thanks, I just gave a static address to my DD-WRT router and provided the right gateway in the DHCP setting and all works perfectly in a single network. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why using the WAN port on the router doesn't work. Not using it was the solution for me, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Jon, because the WAN port is for access to the rest of the Internet, which is separate from your LAN and has no access to computers on your LAN unless you configure the router to forward specific ports to specific computers on your LAN.