# How do I connect to the internet from a dd-wrt router plugged into a modem-router combination?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I've got a cable modem (A) which is also a wireless router and a dd-wrt wireless router (B).

I've connected (B)'s "internet" port to one of (A)'s local ports.

I can connect to (B) over the air just fine, but when connected, cannot connect to the internet.

Questions like [How to bring Internet to a DD-WRT router from another router?](https://superuser.com/questions/716948/how-to-bring-internet-to-a-dd-wrt-router-from-another-router) seem to indicate I shouldn't have to do anything at all.

Comment: Did you disable B's DHCP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect the WAN port of router B to a LAN port on router A.  You have to set the WAN address to DHCP and take whatever address router A issues to it.  Set router B to have a network address range different then router A.